# Fetching data on IOS react redux

Tags: ios, reactjs, safari, redux, fetch

I'm building my first application using react and redux, and for some reason, the structure of the data received on a Async action is behaving different on the IOS (safari).

This action makes the fetch (cross-fetch) request:

```
export function fetchTransactions() {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(requestTransactions());
    return fetch('/getTransactions', {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Cache: 'no-cache',
      },
      credentials: 'same-origin',
    })
      .then(
        response => response.json(),
        error => console.log('An error occurred.', error),
      )
      .then(json => dispatch(receiveTransactions(json.dados)));
  };
}
```

And the receive action is:

```
export const RECEIVE_TRANSACTIONS = 'RECEIVE_TRANSACTIONS';
export function receiveTransactions(data) {
  return {
    type: RECEIVE_TRANSACTIONS,
    data,
  };
}
```

Reducer

```
case 'REQUEST_TRANSACTIONS':
      return Object.assign({}, {...state}, {isFetching: true});
    case 'RECEIVE_TRANSACTIONS':
      return Object.assign({}, {...state}, {data: action.data}, {isFetching: false});
```

Now I'll show you the results on Firefox running on linux:
[image]

It works as expected, the transaction data is present on the array called data.

Here is a print screen from a Safari emulator:
[image]

As you can see, the are duplicate fields and other fields. This behavior is causing the application to not work correctly. Any ideas? Thank you very much and sorry about the English thing.

@edit-------------------------------------------

Running the application on other emulator, results in a good state but the data isn't displayed on the table as you can see bellow:

[image]

As you can see, there are 100 data objects in the array, and nothing on the table, this is not happening on firefox or chrome.

Comment: share your reducers code

Comment: Ok, I put the interest part of the reducer.

Comment: @DenysKotsur I don't think this is a problem with the redux, because even the action data has duplicated fields.